Using Compilation at later stages in generation pipeline
My generator needs to find all types in referenced projects which meet a specific criteria and generate a class for each of them using their method return types.
Example input (in a referenced project, not the one that references generator):
class SuitableClass
{
     public CustomType1 GetCustomType1() { ... }
     public CustomType2 GetCustomType2() { ... }
}

class SuitableClass2
{
     public CustomType3 GetCustomType4() { ... }
     public CustomType4 GetCustomType4() { ... }
}

Example output:
public class SuitableClassGenerated
{
    public void Handle(CustomType1) { ... }
    public void Handle(CustomType2) { ... }
}

public class SuitableClass2Generated
{
    public void Handle(CustomType3) { ... }
    public void Handle(CustomType4) { ... }
}

Generator code:
public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context)
{
    IncrementalValuesProvider<string> typeNames = context
        .CompilationProvider
        .SelectMany((c, _) => GetAllSupportedTypes(c.SourceModule.ReferencedAssemblySymbols)
            .Select(x => x.ContainingNamespace.ToDisplayString() + "." + x.MetadataName));

    IncrementalValuesProvider<Info> generationInput = typeNames
        .Combine(context.CompilationProvider)
        .Select((c, _) =>
        {
            var clientType = c.Right.GetTypeByMetadataName(c.Left);
            if (clientType == null)
                return default;
            return new Info(clientType.Name,
                clientType.GetMembers().OfType<IMethodSymbol>()
                    .Where(m => m is { DeclaredAccessibility: Accessibility.Public, IsStatic: false, ReturnsVoid: false })
                    .Select(m => m.ReturnType.ToDisplayString())
                    .ToImmutableArray());
        })
        .Where(x => x.Methods != null);

    context.RegisterSourceOutput(generationInput,
        (ctx, input) =>
        {
            var code = GenerateCode(input);
            if (code != null)
                ctx.AddSource($"{input.Name}.g.cs", code);
        });
}

record struct Info(string Name, ImmutableArray<string> Methods);

As you see, the two stages require an access to Compilation which breaks the whole caching idea. Is there a way to make caching work so that some stages can be omitted? For an example, if I add a method with a new return type, I only need the second stage to be rerun.
Is there a way to rewrite such multi-stage Compilation-related pipeline to make it more cache-friendly?

Why do you access the CompilationProvider and not the SyntaxProvider? Any specific reason? Furthermore how do you determine the suitable class, via an attribute?

@MaikHasler, as far as I know, SyntaxProvider can only access items in the current assembly but I need to inspect the dependencies. There is no point in referencing the generator from inside those dependencies because the code I need to inspect is generated there by another generator so it will not be visible. I determine suitable class by a specific name and modifiers (public, static) and by method signatures inside (specific name pattern, modifiers, returning non void, absence of other members). I also need to inspect properties on the return types.
